# Two regular expressions in C# - what's the difference?

Tags: regex

What is a difference between following regular expressions

```
Write(?:Line)?
```

and

```
Write(Line)?
```

I am asking that for:

1. Understand the concept
2. Need to write regular expression which will match the following variations for the word `International`:`Int,Tntl,International`

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx#grouping_constructs

Comment: @MattBurland-I saw the link.it looks great. but I still don`t understand the difference. why both notations are needed?

Comment: @SimonC - I saw the post before asking.didn`t find there the answer

Comment: The `(?:Line)` is a *non capturing* group. The string `Line` must be matched, but it won't be included in the output. In the second case, the string `Line` must be matched and will be included as a capture group.

Comment: @MattBurland - if I only use IsMatchis it matter what I use?

Comment: @Yakov: No. If you don't actually care about the captures, only about whether or not it matches. It *might* perform better in some cases, with some implementations of regular expressions if you use the non-capturing group, but you'd have to profile it. If it's a one-off, I wouldn't worry. If it's called in a large loop, maybe it matters.

Answer (score 4):

A group with `?:` is a non capturing group meaning it would not be included in the result.

```
//Will match a "WriteLine" or "Write", but will ignore the Line in the result
Write(?:Line)?

//*match* -> *captured as* 
//WriteLine -> Write
//Write -> Write
```

```
//Will match a "WriteLine" or "Write"
Write(Line)?

//*match* -> *captured as* 
//WriteLine -> WriteLine
//Write -> Write
```

Regex for the #2

Correct me if I didn't understand correctly.

If you want to replace `Int` or `Tntl` with `International`, do this :

```
var result = Regex.Replace("International:Int,Tntl,International","(Int(ernational)?|Tntl)","International");
// "International:Int,Tntl,International" ->
// "International:International,International,International"
```

The pipe symbol `|` serve as `or` operator for the regular expression.

```
(International|Int|Tntl)
```

Comment: I think you meant `?:`.

Comment: both cases match WriteLine as well as Write

Comment: @Yakov There is no `iff`.

Comment: I probably missing something basic. What is "ignore the Line in the result"?

Comment: What is correct regex for 2. in my question?

Comment: @Xiaoy312-:)I want to use?:.not the list of all possibilities

Comment: @Yakov Could you listen some examples and expected results? Im not sure if I get you.

Comment: @Yakov: what do you mean by you want to use `?:`. We've explained what it's for, I don't see how that relates to your second question.

Comment: yes - you are writing te sequence of all possible values actually.I want to use "?:" regex notation to generate all needed values

Comment: I(?:nt(?:ernational)(?:l))?